# Customize the index colorbar python

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I have a color map code and is working, my problem is that I want the color bar between 0 and 7.0 that are the values min and max, but only obtain 0 and 4.0.

Can you help me with this?

```
Ak = 0.918*(tabla['H']-tabla['mag4_5']-0.08)
ext = plt.figure(1)
plt.hexbin(x, y, Ak, cmap=plt.cm.RdPu)
plt.axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
plt.title(u"Mapa de extinción")
A = np.arange(0.0, 7.0, 0.5)
Ak = plt.colorbar(ticks=A)
Ak.set_label(r"A$_k$")
plt.savefig('plotAk.png')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the range of AK passed into hexbin function is 0~4. y can set

```
A = np.arange(min(AK), max(AK), (max(AK)-min(AK))/20)
```

to show the range of color in colorbar with 20 ticks

y can also magnify AK range to 0~7 by:

```
AK = (AK - min(AK))*7.0/(max(AK)-min(AK))
```

and then pass AK into hexbin function

before magnifying(my own data):

[image]

After magnifying:

[image]

Comment: Hi!! I need do the same now, but with square bins. Have you an idea?